# Alternative of hidden fields Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

This question is more about asking suggestions over a scenario.

I have assigned a project built with MVC .NET. There are 100s of hidden fields on `_Layout.cshtml` page. These all hidden fields have url stored in them.

That means they all are loaded every time layout renders.
I want to optimize this situation by removing all hidden fields from layout.

To do this I am thinking of maintaining a local .JSON file which will have `objectName` same as id of hidden fields'.

So if a hidden field is -

```
<input type="hidden" id="myId" value="www.google.com"/>
```

Then .json goes to -

```
{
  "myId":"www.google.com"
}
```

So It would be easy for me to access its value.

Is there anyway better I can do this?

Comment: You want these urls to go to client and come back to server ? Are you modifying them on client? Are you using these values at server side to perform validation or something/

Comment: If these links or Ids have relevant html elements inside the DOM then i recommend you store them as attributes for each relevant element. Otherwise, its difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, Locally only. No server includes.

Comment: @HoussamHamdan, Admired. But this is the longest way possible as I would have to go through each tag. I desire quickest way possible.

Comment: What I mean by client is browser and the view where you have hidden fields. The server means the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

instead why dont you create a singleton class and save them in that as a list  and then whenever you need in view al you need is to just parse it to local javascript variable by @html.Raw(YOUSCingletonClass) and you will get all the values

Comment: You are right but in this case I would have to build it as .dll always. This way If I need any changes locally on server then I would have to post a dll for this trivial change.